# Pass parameters as BSTR or _bstr_t?

Tags: c++, com

My COM-implementing classes take parameters as `BSTR` (and `VARIANT*`) and these get passed around internally. Generally we convert them to `std::string` or `std::wstring` but some times they are getting pased around and will be sent back into another COM call.

**In these cases is it better to pass raw COM types around, or wrap them in helper-classes like `_bstr_t` and `_variant_t`?**

Comment: The _bstr_t and _variant_t are used to manage the resources allocated for BSTRs and VARIANTs. Typically, by wrapping a BSTR (which presumably references system resources) in an auto-variable _bstr_t you can make your code cleaner by avoiding the need to deallocate the resources, as the _bstr_t  destructor will do it for you when it goes out of scope. So the question is not whether it gets passed to another COM call, but whether or not you are responsible for the resources.

Comment: To elaborate on this, any BSTR you receive as pure `in` parameter is purely the responsibility of the caller. You could wrap them in _bstr_t (which would create a copy of them), but that feels unnecessary. Variants are a more complicated matter though, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you do nothing special with a BSTR but just pass it to another method, then you don't have to wrap it. You can see the BSTR as an opaque pointer.

_bstr_t (or CComBSTR which is another wrapper provider with Visual Studio) is useful when you need to allocate BSTR and don't want to manage memory yourself (and make sure you're not leaking memory), but they are not mandatory.

PS: unless I need to *output* a BSTR to a program that doesn't understand Unicode, I would *never* use an intermediary `std:string` to pass BSTRs around, as I would take the risk of losing information. `std:wstring` is better.

Comment: Re. the last comment, `std::string` could be used if it is storing UTF-8.  This is a popular way of handing unicode in C++.

Comment: @M.M - you're right (although I think it's a bad idea especially on the Windows platform)